# Alamofire RequestAdapter - modify URL

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have an app that communicates with physical devices, of which each provides its own URL for communication.

```
class Device {
    let commsUrl: URL
    let serialNo: String
}
```

I have one common Alamofire `SessionManager` for all requests related to these devices (in my own framework). Requests are being provided to the Alamofire RequestAdapter subclass:

```
class DeviceRequestAdapter: RequestAdapter {
    func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest) throws -> URLRequest {
       var urlRequestModified = URLRequest(url: device.commsUrl)
       // set headers etc...
       return urlRequestModified
    }
}
```

Unfortunately when I look into Charles logs, Alamofire sends **two requests at the same time**, one with original URL and another with modified URL (and modified headers). How to fix this? Do I need to create a new SessionManager for each of these devices?

EDIT: 
Code for creating requests:

```
func request(device: Device, command: Device.Command) -> URLRequest? {
    let rawRequest = DeviceCommandRequest(command: command, url: device.commsUrl) //sets appropriate endpoint and JSON content

    guard let dataRequest = try? rawRequest.dataRequest(), //dataRequest() is a convenience function to create a request using SessionManager
          let urlRequest = dataRequest.request
    else {
        return nil
    }

    let adapter = DeviceRequestAdapter(device: device)

    return try? adapter.adapt(urlRequest)
}
```

Adapter:

```
class DeviceRequestAdapter: RequestAdapter {

    private func adaptURL() -> URL? {
        // return modified URL based on Device url and serialNo
    }

    func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest) throws -> URLRequest {
        guard let body = urlRequest.httpBody, let url = adaptURL() else {
             return urlRequest
        }
        var newRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        newRequest.setValue("something", forHTTPHeaderField: "headerField") //and other modifications

        return newRequest
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what you are doing here with multiple devices? also it would be nice to see what your code looks like that is making the requests.

Comment: I just send a command to them with appropriate JSON in the body (eg. start working), but to be able to do that I have to use the URL that device is providing to me (I have no way to set it).

Comment: Do you have something like `sessionManager.adapter = DeviceRequestAdapter(device: device)` in your code?

Comment: No because I created my network classes to have one common session manager. Do I have to refactor it and create separate manager per device...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I refactored the code so that each device has its own session manager. Apparently you can't change a request's URL using the `RequestAdapter`.